# Text Classification Using a Convolutional Neural Network on MXNet with R

Tags: python, r, neural-network, conv-neural-network, mxnet

I'm trying to replicate [this tutorial](http://mxnet.io/tutorials/nlp/cnn.html) from MXNet in R, but have failed to keep track of all the dicts and tuples from Python.

I was wondering whether some of you awesome people have had succes doing the same thing and wouldn't mind sharing?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you done so far? What has worked, what hasn't? Code?

Comment: Hi Patrick! Thanks for your answer. So far I've managed to replicate everything until "cnn_exec = cnn.bind(ctx=ctx, args=arg_arrays, args_grad=args_grad, grad_req='add')", but I'm still not sure if every step is correct as i haven't been able to run a full epoch yet. I never managed to get cnn.bind part to work and now I'm stuck..

Comment: https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet/blob/master/R-package/demo/basic_executor.R shows how to use bind from R. Does that help?

Comment: Hi Indhu. Thanks for your answer. I tired that, but without any luck. "mx.symbol.simple.bind()" Doesn't help much either. I might be using both wrong though. My errors might also be caused by some formatting errors previously - hard to say. What I'm looking for is really a complete example...